# How to re-attach jQuery functions after AJAX content load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

There are a few jQuery UI functions that I call this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".accordion").accordion();
});
```

But my page is AJAX based and some pages may use accordion, some may not use it. There are like 30+ other functions that would need to be re-attached which is a problematic development task. Is there any clever way to fix this so that every new `.accordion` gets this attached automatically?

Possible solutions and why they won't work:

- triggering document ready on AJAX call finish would be ideal but that's not possible
- having `load()` is not an option because it's a CMS where users can install plugins - that means unknown number of unknown functions that plugins add only using `jQuery(document).ready();`
- re-attach functions on `ajaxComplete` - with unknown number of unknown functions this won't work without modifying AJAX script each time you install or uninstall a jQuery plugin

Comment: Are you building a single page webapp? Have you considered a framework like Backbone?

Comment: Careful calling `$(".accordion").accordion()` multiple times because plugins don't necesarily handle several initializations on the same element correctly. To be on the safe side I'd recommend restraining the call to the new content only, e.g. `$("#newContent .accordion").accordion()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `DOMNodeInserted` event and check for the accordion class.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    var el = $(e.target);
    if(el.hasClass('accordion')) {
        el.accordion();
    }
});
```

Example use of DOMNodeInserted: http://jsfiddle.net/qErHs/

Comment: I like this solution a lot :) However, I came to conclusion that it's going to be simpler to just disable AJAX. It's going to be visually worse but technically better.

Comment: FYI DOMNodeInserted is deprecated and its usage is discouraged due to performance implications and cross browser compatibility issues, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events

Comment: @Paul don't ditch ajax, your workaround can be as simple as writing a generic `contentReloaded` function that reinitializes all the necessary plugins, and then call it always on the complete/success callback of any ajax callback. This is what I'd usually do, it's not specially heavy to mantain and it works. (you just would have to remember to update it when you add new plugins)

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar issue with jQuery widgets. What I did was use the ajaxComplete method to attach the widgets.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function()
    {
        $(".accordion").accordion();
    });
```

that way, the function gets called every time an AJAX method is complete and will attach the accordion to any new elements with class accordion

Comment: Thanks for an answer but that's exactly what I want to avoid :) I simply don't know how many functions and what functions will need to be attached because that dynamically changes... Ideal solution would be to trigger `document ready` - this would cover everything I need but that's not possible.

Comment: not sure if it's any better, but what I did before ajaxComplete, was have inline JS in what was returned by the AJAX call to do specific jQuery stuff for the HTML returned

Comment: @Paul you could wrap your document.ready in a separate function (say, `startUI()`) and then call it both on document.ready and when ajax calls are done. But it's probably a better idea to handle document.ready and content reload separately.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you so much for your suggestions, indeed that's another good idea :) But I think that there is no elegant and perfect solution to what I'm looking for so I'll just disable AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/on/

"Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time."

```
jQuery(document).on("change", ".accordion", function() {
  jQuery(".accordion").accordion();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a first suggestion that will fix at least a part of the functions :) But your example should be this: `jQuery(document).on('click', '.selector', function(){});` because `on()` will work this way only then.

Comment: And... it shouldn't happen on click but on element's appearance.

Comment: You're right. I threw that up as I was getting pinged at work. Sorry. I've updated my answer and switched to change().

Comment: Thanks! That definitely is a good solution but I came to conclusion that it's going to be simpler to just disable AJAX. It's going to be visually worse but technically better.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for ".accordeon"-length. Just create a function...

```
function init_accordeon(){
    if($('.accordeon').length) {
        $(".accordon").accordeon();
    }
}
```

and than call this function after your ajax_calls.

Comment: This times 30 functions is not what I'm looking for. I need it to happen automatically. Like with `load()`.

Comment: You need just 1 function. Please check http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ to call it everytime, when your ajax_request finishs

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to call anything after AJAX request complete. I have unknown number of unknown functions in document ready (user can add his own functions) so he would also have to modify ajaxComplete each time he registers a new jQuery plugin.

Comment: therefore i added a if statement which checks for '.accordeon'. By the way. You have to init a plugin, when your dom changes. If you dont want this, try to solve it via iframes

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger custom events after ajax call.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>on demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    color: red;
  }
  span {
    color: blue;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Has an attached custom event.</p>
<button>Trigger custom event</button>
<span style="display:none;"></span>

<script>
$( "p" ).on( "myCustomEvent", function( event, myName ) {
  $( this ).text( myName + ", hi there!" );
  $( "span" )
    .stop()
    .css( "opacity", 1 )
    .text( "myName = " + myName )
    .fadeIn( 30 )
    .fadeOut( 1000 );
});
$( "button" ).click(function () {
  $( "p" ).trigger( "myCustomEvent", [ "John" ] );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```