# Bootstrap Accordion Collapse, final element does not open

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating an Accordion element on a page. On load the accordion works fine. I have a button that adds a group and rebuilds the accordion. Once it's rebuilt, everything works fine except the final group. It will not expand. There are no errors or odd behavior other than it just not opening.  If I refresh the entire page, the added group is still there, but the accordion works properly. I've checked the code before the refresh and after the refresh. The HTML is identical, except for the class in the final  element, which is normally just 'class', but now it is 'class=""'.  As this is controlled by BootStrap itself, I don't seem to be able to find what is causing the error.  Any ideas?

HTML generated from javascript:

```
<div id="static_group_list">
    <div class="panel-group" id="groupAG">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#groupAG" href="#collapse_group1" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">First Test Group</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse_group1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Staff Member</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#groupAG" href="#collapse_group2" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">Second Test Group</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse_group2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Staff Member</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#groupAG" href="#collapse_group3" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">Third Test Group</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse_group3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Staff Member</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#groupAG" href="#collapse_group4" class="" aria-expanded="true">Fourth Test Group</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse_group4" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Staff Member</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

excerpt of Javascript used to generate Accordion element:

```
function create_group_response(){
  if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
      if(xmlHttp.status == 200){
          var xmlDoc=xmlHttp.responseXML;
          var msg = '';
          if ('success' == xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("result")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue){
              var group = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("group");
              var group_num = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("group_num");
              var staff_groups = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("staff_groups");
              var staff_groups_active = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("staff_groups_active");
              var staff_group_ident = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("staff_group_ident");
              msg += '<div class="panel-group" id="groupAG">';
              for (n=0;n<group_num.length;n++){
                  var group_n = group_num[n].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                  var group_g = staff_groups[n].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                  var group_a = staff_groups_active[n].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                  var group_i = staff_group_ident[n].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                 if (1 == group_a && 1 == group_i){
                      var staff_group_staffname = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("staff_group_staffname" + group_n);
                      msg += '<div class="panel panel-default">';
                          msg += '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">'; // role="tab" not part of original code, added as attempt to solve issue from research.
                              msg += '<h4 class="panel-title">';
                                  msg += '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#groupAG" href="#collapse_group' + group_n + '">';
                                      msg += group_g;
                                  msg += '</a>';
                              msg += '</h4>';
                          msg += '</div>';
                          msg += '<div id="collapse_group' + group_n + '" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">'; // role="tabpanel" not part of original code, added as an attempt to solve issue.
                              msg += '<div class="panel-body">';
                                  msg += '<table class="table table-condensed">';
                                      msg += '<tr>';
                                          msg += '<th>Staff Member</th>';
                                      msg += '</tr>';
                                      for (s=0;s<staff_group_staffname.length;s++){
                                          var s_g_s = staff_group_staffname[s].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                          msg += '<tr>';
                                              msg += '<td>' + s_g_s + '</td>';
                                          msg += '</tr>';
                                      }
                                  msg += '</table>';
                              msg += '</div>';
                          msg += '</div>';
                      msg += '</div>';
                  }
              }
              msg += '</div>';
              document.getElementById("static_group_list").innerHTML = msg;
              document.getElementById("createResponse").innerHTML = 'Group Created Successfully!';
              document.getElementById("groupAG").reload; //part of a previous attempt to solve issue.
          } else {
              msg = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("result")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
              document.getElementById('createResponse').innerHTML = msg;
          } 
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: Do you call the function to reattach your accordeons after your ajax call?  Check this SO solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692396/how-to-re-attach-jquery-functions-after-ajax-content-load  .

Comment: @user - just tried it, no luck. Didn't think it would matter anyway, as the first three collapse elements work fine. It's just the last that won't expand correctly.